# Extracting a substring - the Active Power Profile GUID

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

This is the idea I am going for

```
Powercfg -getactivescheme > activeprofile.out
SET /p str=<activeprofile.out
set str=%str:*GUID: =%
set str=%str: (*=%
```

Through repeated testing it seems that I can't have the wild card at the end of the search term. How can I remove `(Power Profile)` from the end of the string?

I don't want to resort to expecting it will be a particular power profile, and I'd rather not attempt removing all the possibilities individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1-4" %A in ('Powercfg -getactivescheme') do Echo %A %B %C %D
```

Is how to. See `for /?` for help.

Or just the guid,

```
for /f "tokens=4" %A in ('Powercfg -getactivescheme') do Echo %A
```

Use `%%<a letter>` in a batch file and `%<a letter>` when typing in the console.

Comment: Do you have a syntax error? That line won't run successfully.

Comment: It will if typed. If in a batch change `%A` to `%%A` for all letters.